# i want to show text box when i click on a radio button using if and else

Tags: javascript, html

```
function show() { document.getElementById('debit').style.display = 'block'; }
function hide() { document.getElementById('credit').style.display = 'none'; }
```

If I click on the debit radio button show me the debit text box and make the credit text box disappear and if I click on credit radio button so automatically disappear the  debit text box other the  disappear both of the text box by default, below is my HTML.

```
<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="num" VALUE="debit" onclick="hide();"/>A 
<INPUT TYPE=RADIO NAME="num" VALUE="credit" onclick="show();"/>B 

<input type="number" id="debit" name="debit" placeholder="debit">
<input type="number" id="credit" name="credit" placeholder="credit">
```

Comment: I guess that you want to know how you could implement the logic for displaying an inputfield depending on which radiobutton got klicked, or?

Comment: i think the logic like this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Dxwvq

Comment: @krish it's not working the logic is correct

Comment: @user27852 : you mean this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bJlaj

Comment: who has voted me -1 here i am new here :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe are you looking for something like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
      document.getElementById('debit').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('credit').style.display = 'none';
    }
    function showDebit() { document.getElementById('credit').style.display = 'none'; document.getElementById('debit').style.display = 'block'; }
    function showCredit() { document.getElementById('credit').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('debit').style.display = 'none'; }
  </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
  <input type="RADIO" name="num" value="debit" onclick="showDebit();" />A 
  <input type="RADIO" name="num" value="credit" onclick="showCredit();" />B 

  <input type="number" id="debit" name="debit" placeholder="debit">
  <input type="number" id="credit" name="credit" placeholder="credit">


</body>
</html>
```